# Approximation property for Banach space and $l^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, compactness

Let's consider a compact operator $T: X \rightarrow l^{p}, 1 \leq p < \infty$. I would like to check, whether it's possible to approximate $T$ by the operators of a finite rank with respect to an operator norm.

For Hilbert spaces it's known that any compact operator can be approximated by the finite rank operator with respect to operator norm (moreover, the statement holds for any space that admits Schauder basis). For arbitrary Banach spaces the property does not hold (there are some counterexamples constructed).

How to check, if in that particular case the approximation property holds?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does $l^p$ admit a Schauder basis?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure, it admits monotone Schauder basis, consisting of unit vectors. Moreover, any orthonormal basis is a Schauder basis in $l^{p}$, since it's separable.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the question. You want a strategy to (explicitly) find finite-rank approximations for a given compact operator?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm familiar with the result, stating that the space of compact operators on a Hilbert space $K(H)$ coincides with the closure of a space of all bounded finite-dimensional operators. In case $H$ is separable, for a taken basis $\{e_{n} \}$ we can consider $P_{n} $  - a projector onto $span\{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{n} \}$. Then, for any $K \in K(H)$, we'll get $||K-P_{n}K|| \to 0$. Seems that here we're considering operators from $H$ to itself, whereas in the situation described in the question is different.

Comment: Well, for $p \neq 2$, $l^p$ is not a Hilbert space. But the same construction works. So I'm unsure what the problem is. Have you problems proving it?

Comment: Ah, your problem is that here the domain of the operator is arbitrary? Doesn't matter a bit, same construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Banach space $E$ has [the approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) if and only if for every Banach space $X$ every compact operator $T\colon X\to E$ is approximable by finite-rank operators. Certainly, $\ell_p$ has the approximation property having a Schauder basis.

For the proof of the general statement see, *e.g.*, Proposition 4.12 in Ryan's *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces*.